# Scheme if statement. Why does this display statement not run?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I am running the following code:

```
(define (myignore x)
    0
)
(define (myinterpreter mylist)
  (evaluate mylist)
)

(define (evaluate mylist)

  (if (eqv? (car mylist) 'prog)
    (evaluate (cdr mylist))
    (display (integer? (car mylist)))
    (if (integer? (car mylist))
      (display "YESSS")
    )
  )

  (if (eqv? (car mylist) 'myignore)
    (myignore (cdr mylist))
  )

)

(myinterpreter '(prog 5))
```

I am wondering why the line containing (display ("YESSS")) does not run despite the (display (integer? (car mylist))) equaling true right before the line runs?

Comment: What Scheme dialect are you using?

Comment: Whichever is running on this site https://repl.it/languages/scheme. I believe scheme48?

Comment: It says BiwaScheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of `if` is:

```
(if predicate
    consequent
    optional-alternative)
```

In your code, `consequent` is `(evaluate (cdr mylist))` and `optional-alternative` is `(display (integer? (car mylist)))`. Everything after that is ignored.

If you want to execute multiple expressions, you have to wrap them in `begin`.

```
(define (evaluate mylist)

  (if (eqv? (car mylist) 'prog)
    (evaluate (cdr mylist))
    (begin 
      (display (integer? (car mylist)))
      (if (integer? (car mylist))
        (display "YESSS")
      )
    )
  )

  (if (eqv? (car mylist) 'myignore)
    (myignore (cdr mylist))
  )

)
```

Comment: what if U just want to insert inside any possible if statement? I tried wrapping `(display "hello)` inside `(begin)`but it didn't work.

Comment: `(begin (display "hello"))` should work fine. Without seeing the complete code I can't tell what you did wrong.

Comment: You're missing the `"` at the end of `"hello`. Is that a copying error or in the code that didn't work?

Comment: I must have had a typo. Wrapping it in `begin` does indeed work. `(define (value a b)
    (if (> a b) "A"
    (begin 
        (display "A is greater")
    )
    )
    (if (> b a) "B"
    (begin 
        (display "B is greater")
    )
    )
)
(value 1 2)`. This is a demo.

Comment: Of course, there's no need to use `begin` if you're only executing one expression.